# What is the standard icon for "smartphone" and "old-fashioned phone?

Tags: icons, iconography

I want to use icons to represent whether you got an smartphone or just an old-fashioned phone in a web form.

What icons may be recognized by all people for this?

Ps. I can use a tooltip.

Comment: might be useful to explain why you'd want to do this? If I've a phone it can make calls and most likely has the ability to access the internet so in the users mind they are one in the same - their phone is no different to someone else's.

Comment: I mean, an eligible phone to install apps, but I don't want to put only Android and iPhone.

Comment: OK so those icons are those for the OS's you're going to support, that keeps them clear and simple. Apps are written for each device, however if you mean a mobile site then if its coded well and uses device detection you should aim to offer an experience for all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Smartphone:** Rounded rectangle with little blocks on them (like iphone, android etc)

**Dumbphone:** Rounded rectangle with a square screen at top, numbers at bottom, and antenna protruding at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Check what the guys at Yummygum made for the iconsweets2 series. They have several variations of the phone icon:

http://iconsweets2.com/